# Ignore files on the gitignore of the base branch being merged to

Tags: git

Here's my situation:

I'm contributing to an open source project, but also want to have a separate branch -- let's call it `config` -- on my own fork where I configure the app to run on my server.

For the upstream branch (master branch of the main repo), I want to merge & track files normally. However, when I merge to my personal configuration branch, there are some files like `setting.py`, the sqlite files, etc., that I do not want to be merged. Those files are listed in the gitignore of `config`, but not the main upstream branch, or the branch I'm developing on.

Is there any way to ignore the files on the gitignore of `config` when merging my development branch, but not when I'm merging upstream, other than manually doing it?

Comment: This may be of no use but it is also possible to ignore files via the .git/info/exclude file - unlike .gitignore this file is not tracked so perhaps it might help somehow?

Comment: @haggisandchips Yeah that actually seems helpful, I'll work on a solution using that